# How to fix incorrect file output after reading characters from a stack

Tags: c++, loops, stack, fstream

My program is writing incorrect data to my output file And I am not sure why this is happening. I am essentially trying to check if an equation is balanced by determining if there are any missing brackets or parenthesis. These equations are being read from an inputfile. To check if they are balanced, I am using a stack. For whatever reason, my program is either over-counting the amount of missing characters or not even recognizing that a character is missing.

From the testing I have tried to do, it seems that my program might be looping more times that it should in some places. However, I am not entirely sure. I have also tried to test my program with a smaller input size, but that did not work.

Here is the relevant code. It should be noted that this is for an assignment where I am challenged to not to use the STL template. My functions for the stack fundamentally work the same way. My pop function removes whatever is at the top of the stack, and copies it to a character variable

```
//create stack
DynStack mystack;

//pushes elements to stack
for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    if (array[i] == '(' || array[i] == '[') {

        mystack.push( array[i] );
        continue;
    }

    // Stack will remain empty until an
    // an open character is reached.
    // While empty, opening characters are missing
    if ( mystack.isEmpty() ) {

        if (array[i] == ')') {

            closedP++;
        }

        else if ( array[i] == ']' )
      ;
        ClosedB++;
    }



    //compares stack to elements in array.
    // if the do not match, then an element is missing.
    if (array[i] == ')') {
        mystack.pop(c);

        if ( c == '[' ) {
            openP++;
        }
    }

    if ( array[i] == ']' ) {
        mystack.pop(c);

        if (c == '(') {
            OpenB++;
        }
    }
}


//if there is still an element left in the stack
//after checking the entire expression, it is either
//missing a ')' or a ']'
if (!mystack.isEmpty()) {
    mystack.pop(c);
    if (c == '(') {
        closedP++;
    }
    else if (c == '[')
        ClosedB++;
}

// cout<<"OP: "<<openP<<endl<<"CP: "<<closedP<<endl<<
// "OpenB "<<OpenB<<endl<<"CB: "<<ClosedB<<endl;
//  cout<<"total: "<<totalmissing<<endl;

totalmissing=openP+closedP+OpenB+ClosedB;

//prints valid expression
if (totalmissing == 0) {
    outfile<<math<<" "<< "=== "
    <<"valid expression"<<endl;
}

//prints the amount of each element missing to output file
//if the number of missing elements is less than 6
if ( totalmissing >= 1 && totalmissing < 6 ) {
    outfile<<math<<" "<< "=== "<<"missing "
    <<"("<<openP<<") "<<"('s"<<" and "<<"("<<closedP<<") "<<")'s"
    <<" and "<<"("<<OpenB<<") "<<"['s"<<" and "<<"("<<ClosedB
    <<") "<<"]'s"<<endl;
}

// expression is missing 6 or more elements
if (totalmissing >= 6 || OpenB >=6
    || ClosedB>=6 ||openP >=6 || closedP >=6 ) {
    outfile<<math<<" "<<"6 or more elements are missing"<<endl;
}
```

Given my input of something like this:

```
a+(b/c)*abcd(efgh
(60+[efg]+[efm)
70+1]
)aphids(
]dkdjsfg-4tw[abds()
```

I am supposed to tell the user if the expression is valid and if its not, tell the what is missing. If there are more than 6 missing I am supposed to tell them so.

As you will see based on what I have given you, my output for whatever is wrong with the expressions I provided is incorrect.

```
a+(b/c)*abcd(efgh 6 or more elements are missing
(60+[efg]+[efm) === missing (1) ('s and (1) )'s and (0) ['s and (0) ]'s
70+1] 6 or more elements are missing
)aphids( 6 or more elements are missing
]dkdjsfg-4tw[abds() 6 or more elements are missing
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just to test, replace your home-made stack with `std::stack<char>`.  Does your code work then?  If so, then the issue is with your home-made stack class, and not the code you posted.  All of that nonsense that you can't use STL -- at least use it to check whether your basic code actually works.

Comment: Also, please format your code properly, i.e. remove the excess spaces between lines.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I considered how that might be a possibility, but our stack was created manually with the help of our textbook. I just followed that.

Comment: All you have to do is replace one line: `DynStack mystack;` with `std::stack<char> mystack;`.  When posting code, you should post a [mcve], and no one except you and your classmates knows what `DynStack` is.

Comment: Paul's point is not to discard the stack, it's to test your program with a stack you can trust works correctly. If the code performs as expected with `std::stack`, you now know where the bug is, your stack, and you can fix it. If you don't get the expected behaviour, you can fix the code that uses the stack without any bugs that may exist in the stack. The point is to isolate problems and attack as few at a time as possible. When you are done, and both the stack and the code that uses the stack are known to be working, you put your stack back.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I’ve gone ahead and done what you recommended in a new project and unfortunately my program is crashing whenever I try to use it. Until I can figure out what is wrong using your method, in regards to mine, do you notice an logical errors, assuming that my functions work in the same way as the template?

Comment: @Schmeep Well, `std::stack` works correctly -- there is nothing wrong with my method -- it is your code that is faulty.  Maybe you're not checking for an empty stack when you call `pop()`?  This is why it is a good idea to use `std::stack` -- we have no idea how your DynStack behaves if you attempt to `pop()` an empty stack.

Comment: @Schmeep `if (array[i] == ')') { mystack.pop(c);` -- If `mystack` is empty and you attempt a `pop`, with `std::stack`, the behavior is undefined (could be a crash).  Using your `DynStack`, if `pop` is written to simply ignore an empty stack, then you've found at least one bug in your code, thanks to `std::stack`, and no thanks to `DynStack`.

Comment: When my new written code doesn't do what it's supposed to (and this is usually the case), I start with staring at the code, continue with staring out of the window, and then (if nothing of that helped, i.e. as a sign of most desperation) debug the code step-wise with small examples and counter-examples. To minimize the last (and most tedious) option, I prefer to insert `assert()`s into my code at any place where I believe to know what should be granted. (It's not meant as offense - just a hint and heads up.)

Comment: You really would get more done if you spend a bit of time getting familiar with your debugger single stepping through the code to understand if it's doing what you expect. Debugging skills pay big dividends in saving time as well as learning.

Answer (score 0):

Proper indentatation is important for reading code. This part looks suspect:

```
if ( mystack.isEmpty() ) {

    if (array[i] == ')') {

        closedP++;
    }

    else if ( array[i] == ']' )
  ;
    ClosedB++;
}
```

In fact it is:

```
if ( mystack.isEmpty() ) {

    if (array[i] == ')') {

        closedP++;
    }

    else if ( array[i] == ']' )
        ;        // noop here
    ClosedB++;   // always executed (if stack is empty)because outside of inner if block
}
```

To avoid such mistakes, I would strongly advise you to be consistent for if blocks: always use curly braces (`{}`) unless the only statement is on the same line as the `if` (or `else if` or `else`) is.

This is enough to explain your incorrect result, but as you did not provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example I could not test whether fixing it is enough to give the expected output.